# When I am exporting a SAS dataset to csv; it is trimming all the leading spaces in the characters

Tags: sas, sas-macro

When I am exporting a SAS dataset to csv; it is trimming all the leading spaces in the characters.
Please help me to retain all the leading spaces in the csv output. The statement used is:

```
Proc Export Data = Globl_Mth_Sumry
OutFile = "&GMUPath.\20&RptYr._&RptMt.\03 Output\01 GMU\&Brnd_Abbr.\&Brnd._&Mkt._Globl_Mth_Sumry_&RptMt.&RptYr.&NeuronQTR..csv" 
DBMS = CSV Replace; 
Run;
```

So, there is a column containing the list of countries which is like

Asia
   India
   China
etc.
But the csv file is showing it like:-
Asia
India
China.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this an interesting question, largely because I was confident I knew the answer... to find out I didn't.

This is technically a solution, and if you're in a time crunch perhaps is sufficient, though I suspect it's too unwieldy to use in a practical fashion.  First I generate the data (input using $CHAR8. to preserve leading spaces), then I output it using fixed column output rather than list output.

```
data test;
input
@1 x $CHAR8.
@9 y $CHAR8.;
format x y $char8.;
datalines;
     USA   China
  Canada N Korea
  Russia  Mexico
;;;;
run;

 data _null_;
 file "c:\temp\test.csv" lrecl=80 dropover;
 set test;
 if _n_ = 1 then do;
 put "x,y";
 end;
 put @1 x $char8. @9 "," @10 y $char8.;
 run;
```

Unfortunately, using DBMS=CSV does not seem to allow $CHAR8. to function as you would expect.  I don't know why that is.  The solution I expected was to write it out like this:

```
data _null_;
file 'c:\temp\test.csv' delimiter=',' DROPOVER lrecl=32767;
  if _n_ = 1 then        /* write column names or labels */
   do;
     put
        "x"
     ','
        "y"
     ;
   end;
 set  TEST;
 put x $ :char8. y $ :char8.;
  run;
```

which is essentially the code printed to the log by PROC EXPORT, then with :$CHAR8. after each variable.  For whatever reason, that (and a bunch of other similar things) didn't work.  ODS CSV also does not seem to work for preserving leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks! I would check it. Meanwhile I did it in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Like Joe, I was intrigued.  It does not appear that `PROC EXPORT` will do what you want.  But here is a SAS macro that might do the trick:

```
%macro mydlm(dsn, outf, dlm, headers);
/*****************************************************************
  MYDLM.SAS
     SAS Macro to create a delimited file from a SAS data set

  Positional Parameters
     DSN     = SAS Dataset Name
     OUTF    = Output Text File
     DLM     = Delimiter to use (CSV, TAB, PIPE, or constant)
     HEADERS = Y or N, Include line with variable names at top

  Example
     %mydlm( sashelp.class , 'c:\temp\tempfile.csv', csv, Y);
 ****************************************************************/

%if       %QUPCASE(&DLM)=CSV  %then %let DLM=%str(,);
%else %if %QUPCASE(&DLM)=TAB  %then %let DLM='09'x;
%else %if %QUPCASE(&DLM)=PIPE %then %let DLM=%str(|);

proc contents noprint data=&DSN
     out=_temp_(keep=name type length varnum label format formatd formatl);
run;
proc sort data=_temp_;
   by varnum;
run;
data _null_;
   set _temp_ end=eof;
   call symput(cats('zvnm',put(_n_,5.)), name);
   if format ne ' '
      then call symput(cats('zvft',put(_n_,5.))
                     , cats(format
                          , put(formatl,best.), '.'
                          , put(formatd,best.))
                       );
   else if type=2
      then call symput(cats('zvft',put(_n_,5.)),cats('$char',put(length,best.),'.'));
      else call symput(cats('zvft',put(_n_,5.)),' ');
   if eof then call symput('zvcnt',left(put(_n_,8.)));
run;
data _null_;
   file &outf;
   set &dsn;

%if %upcase(&headers) = Y %then %do;
   if _n_ = 1 then put

   %do i =1 %to %eval(&zvcnt.-1);
         "'%trim(&&zvnm&i)'" "&dlm"
   %end;
         "'%trim(&&zvnm&zvcnt)'" ;
%end;

   put
   %do i =1 %to %eval(&zvcnt.-1);
       &&zvnm&i &&zvft&i "&dlm"
   %end;
       &&zvnm&i &&zvft&i;
run;
%mend mydlm;
```

The macro lets you choose either CSV, TAB, or PIPE (|) as a delimiter. Character variables will have leading blanks preserved and the width of all variables will be based on any predefined SAS variable formats.  I tested the macro with this sample:

```
data a;
   number2 = 2;
   format num comma7.;
   format date yymmdd10.;
   format char $char40.;
   date = today();
   num = 1; char = '          This has 10 leading blanks'; output;
   num = 2; char = 'This has no leading blanks'; output;
run;
%mydlm( a , 'c:\temp\tempfile.csv', csv, y);
```

**UPDATE:** To give credit, the above code was derived from ideas I found [on this web page](http://www.sconsig.com/sastips/tip00391.htm).  I would have just pointed you to that link but it did not really do what you want.  It's really hard to read as well.

**UPDATE2**:  Revised the example macro to correct a syntax error and make it more generic.  This new version allows you to specify any character string as a column delimiter.  I'm adding this to support [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14608322/1275871), which can be answered using the following macro call:

```
%mydlm( Exp_TXT, '/fbrms01/dev/projects/tadis003/Export_txt_OF_New.txt', ~|~, Y);
```